# Memory for fields of class

Tags: c++

I have such class:

```
class Job{
    public:
        string name;
        double age;

        Job(string name, double age){
            this->age = age;
            this->name = name;
        }
    };
```

If I create object of this class by this way:

```
Job* job = new Job("worker", 45.36);
```

The `new Job(..)` object will be stored at heap, but
where will the memory for `string name` and `double age`be allocated? On stack or at heap?

Comment: The memory for the object (including its members) will be allocated on the heap.

Comment: BTW, if you choose different names for your parameters or methods, you don't need the `this->` notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the C++ language standard does not dictate any of this.

In fact, it doesn't even define either one of these terms (neither *heap* nor *stack*).

The memory section in which objects are allocated is entirely compiler-implementation dependent.

That said, in practice, any "decent" compiler will create an object code such that both fields will be located at a relative offset from the base-address of the containing object (hence in your example they will be placed in the heap).

Answer (score 3):

> The new Job(..) object will be stored at heap

This means that all members of class `Job` will be stored there, so to answer your question, on the heap.

Note that the standard doesn't ever talk about the "heap", the appropriate term is the "free-store".

Answer (score 2):

The Job object itself will be on the heap. The location of the string (meaning where the characters are stored) is up to the implementer of the string class. It is almost certainly on some sort of heap, but maybe not the same heap as the Job object.

If you created a Job object on the stack the string would still be placed in the the location specified by the string implementer.